# How to use $SHELL variable with fish?

Tags: fish

I've recently moved from the `zsh` to the `fish` shell but I occasionally still stumble upon some incompatibilities. Right now I'm trying to install [virtualenv-burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito) but it fails at the `$SHELL` command. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is:

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito/master/virtualenv-burrito.sh | $SHELL
```

The surface problem is that fish deliberately doesn't allow commands to be variables, and therefore piping to $SHELL is not allowed.

However, the deeper problem is that virtualenvwrapper is only for Bourne compatible shells, so even if it's installed it won't work with fish. Instead you can use [virtualfish](https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish).